# Windows error reporting keeps uploading Lots of data

Tags: windows-10

my Windows problem reporting is uploading lots of data non-stop and its 
eating my internet data !

I have already :

- set Diagnostic and usage data to Basic
- Stop Windows Error Reporting Service

But the problem reporter wont stop Uploading data

Whenever I close if from TaskManager it opens itself again after 30Mins

[TaskManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1RCY.png)

Comment: "Stop Windows Error Reporting Service" You need to disable it, not just stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution !

Track the app .exe file location from task manager

Then Go to firewall add outbound rule block connection of the .exe file you located

done !

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked. I used Glaswire to monitor the bandwidth usage and it was obvious that window error reporting was uploading too much, I really don't understand why.